# Java fileds initialization order

Tags: java, static

```
class revi {

    static {
        i = 3;
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
    static int i = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

above program does not give any error at `i=3`; but when we call the `i` in `println()` method of static block it showing error

revi.java:6: error: illegal forward reference
        System.out.println("Hello World!"+i);
                                          ^
1 error

```
class revi {

    static {
        i = 3;
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + i);
    }
    static int i = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

but if modify the above program like this it working(static variable first loaded ) no error in println method

```
class revi {

    static int i = 15;

    static {
        i = 3;
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

please explain internal flow ...

Comment: It is as you can see: static initialization blocks can only refer to static variables declared previously.

Comment: "it showing error" is never enough information. Please tell us what error you're seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in section [8.3.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the following are true:
>
> - The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable;
> - The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a static initializer of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

In your case, all of them *are* true when you're printing the value, hence the error.

After changing your code to move the declaration, the first bullet is no longer true, so it compiles.

Comment: Do you know why they decided that writing `i = 3;` is not an illegal forward reference, whereas writing `System.out.println(i);` is. What's the point?

Comment: @pbabcdefp: I honestly couldn't tell you that. I suspect it's because the former doesn't need the *existing* value to be known, whereas the latter does - it may make it easier to work out the order in which to emit code. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

In case1, You are initializing the variable `i` with `3` and at line 2 with `15`. So end result is that variable `i` holds `15`.

In case 2 you will get `Illegal forward reference error` because you are trying to use the variable `i` before it is defined. **Updated** As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3) static variables that are not yet defined can only be used in the assignment unless they are prefixed with class name(in which case they get there default value). E.g.1

```
static {
    i = 3;
    i = i * 2; // will give you compile error
    System.out.println("Hello World!" );
}
```

E.g.2 In this case you are accessing variable `i` prefixed with class name. But remember that `revi.i` will have value `0` not `15`, so the output will be `0`

```
static {
    i = revi.i * 2; // this line is similar to  revi.i = revi.i * 2;
    System.out.println("Hello World!" + revi.i );
}
static int i = 15;
```

In case 3  first you declared and initialize `i=5` and then assigned 3 to it. So after initialization `i` will hold 3 as its value

Comment: Can you say something more about second case? Why if we use `revi.i` instead of `i` problem disappears `System.out.println("Hello World!" + revi.i);`?

Comment: I was interested more in "why `revi.i` is allowed while `i` isn't", not in "how it will work". IMO JLS just confirms it, not explains. Will need to look a this closer *someday*.

Answer (score 0):

When a java class is getting executed there are few steps which JVM performs few steps sequentially.

Identify the static members from top to bottom.
Executes static variables assignments and static blocks from top to bottom.
Executes the main method.
During these phases there is one such state called RIWO(Read Indirectly Write Only) for a static variable.

During RIWO a variable cannot be accessed directly with its reference. Instead we need to use an indirect way to call certain variables.

[RIWO State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779507/what-is-wiro-write-indirectly-read-out-state/31822445#31822445)

you can refer to that link for detailed information.