# What is RIWO (Read Indirectly Write Out) state

Tags: java, static

I was reading about the static flow control and came across the RIWO concept. Can someone explain this with simple terminology and perhaps a code sample?

This is related to the error "Illegal forward reference".

[Relevant link](http://javadhaba.com/core-java/Static-Control-Flow.html).

Comment: This term isn't in general use. You should quote the source if it is available to the general public. Or follow the references the author ought to have provided unless it is thoroughly explained there.

Comment: added the reference url

Comment: As I see in your referenced url, only RIWO (Read Indirect Write Only) is mentioned.

Comment: This is a badly written section of a tutorial where the initialisation of a class immediately after loading is explained in unnecessary detail. I would not worry trying to understand this "state" of a static variable, and I would try to find a tutorial where this is explained in clearer language with more pertinence to practical code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through some material and discussing with couple of guys offline i found out the following information.

When a java class is getting executed there are few steps which JVM performs few steps sequentially.

- Identify the static members from top to bottom.
- Executes static variables assignments and static blocks from top to bottom.
- Executes the main method.

During these phases there is one such state called RIWO(Read Indirectly Write Only) for a static variable.

During RIWO a variable cannot be accessed directly with its reference. Instead we need to use an indirect way to call certain variables.

for example:

```
class Riwo
{
 static int i = 10;
 static
 {
  System.out.println(i);
 }
 }
```

In the above case the output is 10.

```
class Riwo {
static int i = 10;
static {
    m1();
    System.out.println("block1");
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    m1();
    System.out.println("block main");
}

public static void m1() {
    System.out.println(j);
    System.out.println("block m1");
}

static int j = 20;
static {
    System.out.println("end of code");
}
}
```

In the above case the output is

0
block m1
block1
end of code
20
block m1
block main

```
class Riwo
{
static
{
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println("block1");
}
static int i = 10;
public static void main(String... args)
{
    System.out.println("main block");
}
}
```

In the above case we get the following compile time error

Riwo.java:5: illegal forward reference
                System.out.println(i);

That means we cannot read a static variable directly when it is in RIWO state.We should call the variable indirectly using a method.

Answer (score 2):

Static variable have two states

- RIWO (Read Indirectly Write Only)
- RW(Read Write)
  .

**RIWO:**
     Before assigning original value to static variable, variable state is called as RIWO  state.

**RW:**
     After assigning original value to static variable, variable state is called as RW  state.

Static variable have two type of reading

- Direct Read
- InDirect Read

**Direct Read:**
        Reading static variable from static block  directly is called direct reading.

**InDirect Reading:**
    Reading static variable from static block by calling another method  is called indirect reading.

**Direct Read Example:**
**Note:** when static variable in RIWO state we cant perform **Direct Reading**.

```
class DirectReadingExample{
          static {
                    System.out.println("i==="+i);
                 }
                 //i is in RIWO state
                 static int i=100;
                 //i is in RW State
    }
```

Output:
compile time Error:illegal forward reference.

**InDirect Read Example:**
**Note:** when static variable in RIWO state we can perform **InDirect Reading**.

```
class InDirectReadingExample{
          static {
                    m1();
                 }
          static m1(){
                  System.out.println("i===="+i);
          }
                 //i is in RIWO state
                 static int i=100;
                 //i is in RW State
    }
```

Output:
i===0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read up on how to format the code and text in your answer/question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is just identified by JVM and the original value is not
yet assigned, then the variable is said to be in the RIWO(Read Indirectly Write Only) state.

The following code is legal:

```
class Test{
    static int num=10;
    static
         {
            System.out.print(num);
            System.exit(0);
         }
}  
output: 
10
```

The code below will produce a compile time error(illegal forward reference)

```
class Test{     
    static
         {
            System.out.print(num);
         }
    static int num=10;
} 
//Produces Compile time error
```

The code below is legal:

```
class Test{     
    static
        {
           int x=readVar();
        }
    static int readVar(){
           System.out.println(num);
           return 0;
    }
    static int  num=10;
    static
    {
          System.out.print(num);
    }
}
output: 
0
10
```

In this case, we're not performing a direct read, but rather an indirect 
read via a method call. The variable num is identified by JVM - step 1.
Then the default value 0 is assigned to num at that time.